Gibbs energy and maximum obtainable work
What I've understood about the change in Gibbs energy for a physical process (e.g. isothermal expansion of a gas) is that it's a measure of the maximum obtainable non pV work. I also suppose that this maximum work can only be obtained in a reversible process (I suppose so because Gibbs energy change, I believe, is only a change in entropy in disguise, so that the leftover excess entropy could be avoided by choosing a reversible pathway and converting it into work).
Now, what would be the analogy for chemical processes like electrochemical cell reactions, how can all the Gibbs energy change be converted to electrochemical work, how can the reactions be carried out reversibly in theory? Also is my understanding about change in Gibbs energy actually correct for physical processes?

Review also results for the targeted search site:chemistry.stackexchange.com OR site:chem.libretexts.org Gibbs energy maximum obtainable work

An electrochemical cell is producing voltage and electrical energy (or non-$pV$ work).
Let's state about voltage first. The voltage $E^\circ$ is related to $\Delta G$ of the chemical reaction by the following expression: $$E^\circ = - \frac{\Delta G}{zF},\tag{1}$$ where $z$ is the number of electrons included in the chemical reaction, and $F$ is the Faraday constant. But this $E^\circ$ value is obtained when the reaction is reversible — that is when the cell does not deliver any current. If the cell is delivering some current $I$, the cell does not work in a reversible way. The measured voltage is $E < E^\circ,$ and these two voltages $E^\circ$ and $E$ are related by $$E = E^\circ - R_\mathrm i I,\tag{2}$$ where $R_\mathrm i$ is the internal resistance of the cell.
Let's consider the corresponding electrical energy. The available electric energy per mole of reactant is the product of the voltage times the current and the time. It is equal to $-\Delta G = zFE^\circ$ in the reversible situation, if the cell is not delivering any current. As soon as the cell delivers some current $I,$ the cell is not reversible any more and the available energy is smaller.

If the cell weren't reversible then why would all the change in gibbs energy be converted to electrical work?
